# After mistake in /etc/network/interfaces file configuration, and reboot all 4 interfaces on my server went to "DOWN" state. Bug or not?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

So, I decided to change my server's network configuration, by editing /etc/network/interfaces file. 
I had IPv6 address, and I was changing it to IPv4 address. 
Before changes it looked like that:

```
eno1 auto
iface eno1 inet6 static
address fc00::111:111:111:111
netmask 112

eno2 auto 
iface eno2 inet6 static
address fc00::222:222:222:222
netmask 112
```

While editing the file, I mistakenly put new interface configuration like this:

```
eno1 auto
iface eno1 inet4 static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 24
```

I saved a configuration, and continue my work.
Later, there was a strong need in the reboot, so I rebooted my server and eventually I lost connection to it (I was using SSH). Interface eno1 was not pingable. 
So I went directly to the server (another part of the building), connect a monitor to it, and `"ifconfig"` (or `ip a`) showed me that all 4 interfaces were in `DOWN` state. 
My question is - is it OK? 
Should `iface` just skip mistakes in interfaces configuration, and not put other interfaces to `DOWN` state? As for me, only `eno1` interface should be in `DOWN` state, and other should work, as long as their configuration did not changed. 
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with all updates installed.

EDITED:
`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` does not return anything as long as directory is empty. It was run on server.

EDITED2: 
So I eventually facing the same issue on VM, that I setup for test.
`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` returns:

```
network:
  version:2
  renderer:NetworkManager
```

Comment: Right now I'm installing VM with Ubuntu, to check if I can reproduce the issue and collect logs.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure how it could be a bug if you made a mistake in the configuration.

Comment: It is definitely not expected, that you will lose all of your network interfaces, even if only one has a mistake in configuration.